# Laravel call wrong table when request using api

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have 2 web apps on my local computer.

1. `abc.test` using a database named `abc`,
2. `def.test`, using a database named `def`,

my main goal is to retrieve the `status` located in `def.test` database. using `abc.test`.

here is code from `abc.test`

```
    public function create(): View
        {
            if(!session()->has('license')){
                $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'http://def.test/api/service',[
                    'form_params' => [
                        'license_key' => base64_encode(config('def.license'))
                    ],
                ]);
            }
            return view('auth.login');
        }

and then here is `def.test` controller to handle the request

    public function getSubs(Request $request)
        {
            $license = $this->decryptLicense($request->license_key);
            $subs = Subscription::query()->select('service_id', 'status', 'expired_date')->where('license_key', $license)->first();
            $data = [
                'services' => $subs->service->name,
                'status' => $subs->status,
                'expired_date' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($subs->expired_date)),
            ];
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }
```

when using Postman, it works perfectly. but, when using `abc.test` it shows this error in Laravel log

```
(PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc.subscriptions' doesn't exist at D:\\Program\\laravel\\lausystems\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:416)
```

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Set connection name ([Doc Multiple DB connection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections))

```
DB::connection('abc')->table('statuses').....
```

**UPDATE:**

//Server 1 (abc Server)

```php
//Server 1 (abc Server)
'mysql' => [ // I'll use mysql for default
    'host' 'localhost';
    'sticky' => true,
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'abc',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
'def' => [
    'host' '1.1.1.2'; // IP server 2
    'sticky' => true,
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'def',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

//Server 2 (def Server)

```php
//Server 2 (def Server)
'mysql' => [ // I'll use mysql for default
    'host' 'localhost';
    'sticky' => true,
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'def',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
'abc' => [
    'host' '1.1.1.1'; // IP Server 1
    'sticky' => true,
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'def',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

Or you can merge the both connection on both servers.

Don't forget to grant access to your servers (MySQL) (so server 1 can communicate with server 2 and verse-versa)

Comment: is this gonna work when deploy to separate server ?

Comment: Yes, if both servers has the same database configuration .. I mean both servers has the same database config (Server1 & Server2 can communicate), I'll update my Answer to understand

Comment: even if the both apps has different database structure ?

Comment: You have to provide all the necessary information in on the body of your Question !!!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it may work but that's not what i'm looking for. because i want to create and consume api only. in my case, abc will have multiple project with same code in 1 or more server. but def only 1 project. so it will take a lot of time i guess to configure all the projects. after deploying to server it works pretty well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it may work but that's not what i'm looking for. because i want to create and consume api only. in my case, abc will have multiple project with same code in 1 or more server. but def only 1 project. so it will take a lot of time i guess to configure all the projects. after deploying to server it works pretty well.